# How do I compile from source on github?

Tags: dll, github, compilation, makefile

First off: Here is the thing.
    https://github.com/oscar-broman/sky

It is supposed to be compiled to .dll

I have no idea where to start, but I have tried 'make' in cygwin. This was obviously the wrong approach...

```
$ make
rm -f *~ *.o *.so
gcc -m32 -D SKY -g -c -fPIC -w -D LINUX ./lib/sdk/*.cpp
In file included from ./lib/sdk/plugin.h:8:0,
                 from ./lib/sdk/amxplugin.cpp:13:
./lib/sdk/plugincommon.h:40:4: error: #error "Unknown operating system."
   #error "Unknown operating system."
    ^
In file included from ./lib/sdk/plugin.h:9:0,
                 from ./lib/sdk/amxplugin.cpp:13:
./lib/sdk/amx/amx.h:381:72: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
 int AMXAPI amx_GetString(char *dest,const cell *source, int use_wchar, size_t size);
                                                                        ^
./lib/sdk/amx/amx.h:401:83: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
 int AMXAPI amx_SetString(cell *dest, const char *source, int pack, int use_wchar, size_t size);
                                                                                   ^
./lib/sdk/amxplugin.cpp:142:86: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
 typedef int  AMXAPI (*amx_GetString_t)(char *dest,const cell *source, int use_wchar, size_t size);
                                                                                      ^
./lib/sdk/amxplugin.cpp:143:72: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
 int AMXAPI amx_GetString(char *dest,const cell *source, int use_wchar, size_t size)
                                                                        ^
./lib/sdk/amxplugin.cpp:282:97: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
 typedef int  AMXAPI (*amx_SetString_t)(cell *dest, const char *source, int pack, int use_wchar, size_t size);
                                                                                                 ^
./lib/sdk/amxplugin.cpp:283:83: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
 int AMXAPI amx_SetString(cell *dest, const char *source, int pack, int use_wchar, size_t size)
                                                                                   ^
makefile:22: recipe for target 'SKY' failed
make: *** [SKY] Error 1
```

And I think gcc is [installed](http://pastebin.com/mytd1yUg)

What do I need to do different to compile that source?

Comment: What errors do you get. A cursory look at the makefile suggfesys it uses gcc, do you have that installed in cygwin?

Comment: Here is the errors when typing make: http://pastebin.com/7kMGNVbK  And I think gcc is installed: http://pastebin.com/mytd1yUg And why did I get downvoted for this question? If I did something wrong tell me so I know for future references...

Comment: Please update the question to include the errors etc so that future users can search for them. You probably got downvoted because your question is unclear and doesn't have enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I already added the errors before you said that... Were you going to help me? Thanks btw.

Comment: No, you pasted a link to the errors. Put the _actual_ errors in the question.

Comment: That's like impossible. I've been trying for like the past 20 minutes to properly format it into the post. Blockquotes, fail. >, fail. code, fail.

Comment: 'Whitetiger' added stuff for windows compilation just 17 minutes ago... But I still get the same errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the code.  This code expects to be compiled either on GNU/Linux, or FreeBSD, or OpenBSD using GCC, or else on Windows using MS Visual C++.  It doesn't support being compiled on Windows with GCC (cygwin).

As for formatting, if you [read the docs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of just guessing lots of different things it's a lot easier to make it work.